# What is the better way to set a project in Vue.js + Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I'm doing my first project in Vue.js + Firebase. So I'm having this error
`Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)`

when I used Firestore, into a component.

In **main.js** I have

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

 const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "********",
   authDomain: "*******",
   projectId: "*******",
   storageBucket: "*********",
   messagingSenderId: "*********",
   appId: "*********",
   measurementId: "********"
 };

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

So in **Dashboard.vue**

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
const db = firebase.firestore();
```

in others Views like **Login.vue  Register.vue**

I used

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
```

In these views Works!

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Vue CLI application, I always initialise Firebase in `created()` as shown below:

```
<script>
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth"
import fbConfig from "@/creds/fbConfig.json";

export default {
  name: "ComponentName",
  data: () => ({ }),
  created() {
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig)
    }
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("User is logged in!")
      }
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Though make sure you write this code on every parent Vue Component!
If it is child component like a modal or a section of the page, you don't need to initialise the app.